# StringByAddingPercentEscapes on an array object

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to load images from URL's into a UICollectionView but noticed if the URL had any spaces or special characters it would not load.  I tried to encode it with StringByAddingPercentEscapes but it isn't working for some reason. Can someone look at the code below and see where my problem might be?

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:
  @"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  [cell.myImage setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[picturePaths 
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
  @"placeholder.png"]];
}
```

Comment: Show some actual URL strings from your `picturePaths` array, please (and explain where these strings are coming from).